# update section background colour without refreshing the whole UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a UIViewController which has a UITableView and a button called "A" . This table has sections and rows. Now in my scenario i want to highlight a section  when "A" clicked. I don't want to do this work in viewForHeaderInSection as i don't want to reload the whole table view. The code that i am trying at the moment on button click is as follows,

```
public func scrollToSection(sectionNumber:Int)
    {
      let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: sectionNumber)
      let headerView = tableView.headerViewForSection(indexPath.section)
      tableView.beginUpdates()
      headerView?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
      tableView.endUpdates()
      tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, animated: true)
    }
```

but somehow it is not showing the cyan color on button click. Can anyone please post a proper solution in swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate approach would be to keep a `bool` if the button has been pressed or not.

Then, in your:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

[ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:)

method, change the background color based on that `bool` value. When the button is selected, simple flip the `bool` and call:

```
func reloadSections(_ sections: NSIndexSet, withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

[ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadSections:withRowAnimation:)